# How to use DB default when persist entity in Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have entity class with many fields like so:

```php
/** @ORM\Entity() */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private int $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="add_time") */
    private DateTime $createdAt;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="text", name="full_address") */
    private string $fullAddress;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    private string $street;

    // other fields
}
```

This entity has about 20 fields. Almost all of them are defined as `varchar(100) default ''  not null` in the database.

Now I'm going to do a partial update. So I send just a single field (or sometimes a subset of fields) instead of entire form. Some fields may have an empty value (empty string).

As I understand, I can not use `$form->handleRequest` to populate my entity, so I use

```php
$form->submit($request->request->all(), false);
```

But in this case all fields with empty string value are not set into the entity. And Doctrine generates INSERT statement with full list of fields and pass null values into placeholders, and that causes `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'street' cannot be null`

I tried some solutions, but no one worked for me:

1. Set field default value:

```php
/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
private string $street = '';
```

It produces `Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Entity\Address::setStreet() must be of the type string, null given` on `$form->submit`.

2. Set default in the constructor:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->street = '';
}
```

Exactly the same as the 1st one.

3. Add Doctrine default option:

```php
/** @ORM\Column(type="string", options={"defalt": ""}) */
private string $street = '';
```

No changes at all because `BasicEntityPersister::getInsertColumnList` doen't use this information.

4. After 3rd I tried to implement my own EntityPersister, but it looks like there is no way to do that. Doctrine doesn't allow to change it.

I probbly missed something very symple and stupid.

Is there a way to exclude fields with default values from INSERT statement?

Comment: Your first approach is correct.  It would appear that your form has a input element named street which is causing the setStreet issue.  Remove it from the form and that error will go away.  Or you can change the setStreet method signature to allow for nulls `(?string $street)` and then convert any nulls you do get into an empty string.  For all intents and purposes, Doctrine does not support default database values since not all databases support them.  Don't go down that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit data from the form to the entity, TextType field with empty string value `''` is transformed to the `null` and set by `setStreet()` method. For more information see the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#empty-data, especially the text in the red box.
Empty string value to the null transformation is executed by method `TextType::reverseTransform`.

There are 2 variants to resolve it:

1 - modify setter

```
public function setStreet(?string $street): self
{
    $this->street = (string) $street;

     return $this;
}
```

2 - add a custom view transformer for the TextType fied in the form builder or create a new form type with custom view transformer

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    .....

    $builder->get('street')->addViewTransformer(new NullToEmptyStringTransformer());
}


class NullToEmptyStringTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform(mixed $value): mixed
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function reverseTransform(mixed $value): string
    {
        return (string) $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one worked for me. Full solution: set default values (e.g. in constructor) and cast value to string in setter